# Using sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV with SMOTE oversampling only on training folds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation

I have a highly unbalanced dataset (99.5:0.5). I would like to perform hyperparameter tuning on a Random Forest model using `sklearn`'s `RandomizedSearchCV`. I would like each of the training folds to be oversampled using SMOTE, and then each of the tests to be evaluated on the final fold, keeping the original distribution without any oversampling. Since these test folds are highly unbalanced, I would like the tests to be evaluated using the F1 Score.

I have tried the following:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("data/dataset.csv")

data_x = dataset.drop(["label"], axis=1)
data_y = dataset["label"]

smote = SMOTE()
model = RandomForestClassifier()

pipeline = make_pipeline(smote, model)

grid = {
    "randomforestclassifier__n_estimators": [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000],
    "randomforestclassifier__criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
    "randomforestclassifier__max_depth": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, None],
    "randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20],
    "randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20],
    "randomforestclassifier__max_features": ["auto", None, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
    "randomforestclassifier__bootstrap": [True, False],
    "randomforestclassifier__max_samples": [None, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
}

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, grid, scoring='f1', n_iter=10, n_jobs=-1, cv=kf)

search = search.fit(data_x, data_y)

print(search.best_params_)
```

However, I am not sure if SMOTE is being applied to the test set on each iteration.

How can I ensure that SMOTE is being applied only to the training folds, but not the test fold?

**EDIT:**

[This article](https://kiwidamien.github.io/how-to-do-cross-validation-when-upsampling-data.html) seems to answer my question (specifically in Section 3B), providing sample code of exactly what I am trying to do, and demonstrating how it works the way I have specified I would like

Comment: Irrelevant to the question and out of curiosity - does the pipeline run like that? I would think you need to change the prefix in grid parameters to `model__` instead of  `randomforestclassifier__`. Does it run as you have posted it here?

Comment: Yes, I think `make_pipeline` just reads the name of the class and converts it all to lowercase. Otherwise you can initialise a `Pipeline` object yourself and manually set the names as you wish.

Comment: I have actually now changed my code to `pipeline = Pipeline([("smote", SMOTE()), ("rf", RandomForestClassifier())])` and `grid = {"rf__n_estimators": ... }`

Comment: Yeah, it's obvious that this version will run OK; but I confess that, if asked without being allowed to actually run it, my guess would be that as is in your post would not run.

Comment: It runs fine, I just don't know if it is doing what I want/expect, but I am implementing what I have read in the article linked in my question edit, and will report the results back if it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Removing since I misunderstood. As mentioned in the comment - I'm not sure if using imblearn's pipeline this could be done in the fashion I proposed. Perhaps using sklearn's pipeline and implementing the fit and transform methods yourself and forcing that oversampling only takes place when `fit` is called could be a way @kob ?

Comment: @desertnaut @yatu If you look at section 3B of the article I linked, specifically the last sentence "When predicting, the SMOTE step doesn't do anything (it just passes the values through). We can check this explicitly by just making a prediction from the randomforestclassifier and seeing we get the same result." It appears as though `imblearn`'s `Pipeline` already implements what I am trying to do, by not applying SMOTE to in the `predict` function, which I presume is what is used on the validation fold in `RandomizedSearchCV`.

Comment: Meaning that by checking against a prediction directly with the fitted randomforestclassifier vs the pipeline including a SMOTE, you should get the same results?? Makes sense if that is how imblearn has implemented it :) @kob

Comment: @yatu Yes, I have just done this and it seems to be the case. Posting my code as an answer to my question.

Comment: Kool! @kob Good to know. And thanks for linking the article, will give it a look

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the article linked in my edit, when an `imblearn` `Pipeline` is passed to `sklearn`'s `RandomizedSearchCV`, the transformations appear only to be applied to the data on the training folds, and not the validation folds. (I don't understand how this works though, because if a scaler was passed into the pipeline, for example, you would want this to be applied to ALL the data, not just the training folds).

I tested this with the following code, which actually doesn't do any hyperparameter tuning, but simulates as if parameters where being tuned, and the validation F1 score is almost identical to my final testing F1 score.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd

# TRAIN / TEST SPLIT

dataset = pd.read_csv("data/dataset.csv")

data_x = dataset.drop(["label"], axis=1)
data_y = dataset["label"]

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
    data_x, data_y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True
)

# HYPERPARAMETER TUNING

pipeline = Pipeline([("smote", SMOTE()), ("rf", RandomForestClassifier())])

grid = {
    "rf__n_estimators": [100],
}

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

# Just applies smote to the k-1 training folds, and not to the validation fold
search = RandomizedSearchCV(
    pipeline, grid, scoring="f1", n_iter=1, n_jobs=-1, cv=kf
).fit(train_x, train_y)

best_score = search.best_score_
best_params = {
    key.replace("rf__", ""): value for key, value in search.best_params_.items()
}

print(f"Best Tuning F1 Score: {best_score}")
print(f"Best Tuning Params:   {best_params}")

# EVALUTING BEST MODEL ON TEST SET

best_model = RandomForestClassifier(**best_params).fit(train_x, train_y)

accuracy = best_model.score(test_x, test_y)

test_pred = best_model.predict(test_x)
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(test_y, test_pred).ravel()
conf_mat = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Model (0)": [tn, fn], "Model (1)": [fp, tp]}, index=["Actual (0)", "Actual (1)"],
)

classif_report = classification_report(test_y, test_pred)

feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(
    {"feature": list(train_x.columns), "importance": best_model.feature_importances_}
).sort_values("importance", ascending=False)

print(f"Accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")
print("")

print(conf_mat)
print("")

print(classif_report)
print("")

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", len(feature_importance))
print(feature_importance)
pd.reset_option("display.max_rows")
```

Comment: Maybe you could help wit this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482581/scikit-learn-and-imblearn-does-gridsearchcv-randomsearchcv-apply-preprocessing

Comment: In my case, it did only apply the preprocessing steps of the pipeline to the training set, but there of course are some instances where you would want the preprocessors to be applied to the validation and test sets as well, but I don't understand how you can differentiate between the two cases.